# How are the starting positions in Lúcioball chosen?

Tags: overwatch

In *Lúcioball*, each player starts each round in a different position. One player spawns as the goalie, while the remaining players spawn on offense.

After playing for a while, I haven't been able to find any consistent pattern to know which player will be goalie next. This makes it difficult to plan as a team for who will stay behind and who will charge ahead.

**How does the game decide player spawn locations in *Lúcioball*? Is it random?**

Comment: Why do you think it might not be random if all you see is randomness?

Comment: Based on my observations if you have the least contribution to the team such as 0 in everything after the first goal, you'll be put in the goalie position. This is based on a group of 3 observation.

Comment: This sounds to me like a question about developer intent, which is one of the off-topic close reasons.

Comment: Not to me, he wants to know what criteria make any given player play goal in the next round.  Seems like a solid question.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer it's a valid question. The OP is possibly looking for clarification on patterns or if it's truly random. It's a fine question.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that, to keep the game fair (wouldn't be a fun game if you keep going against a top 500 Lucio main goalie God), the game chooses it at random.